# TypeError when doing cos/sin on FloatProperty

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on an Android App that has to comunicate with a server to store/retrieve models in a database. Models have two parameters latitude and longitude, that are FloatProperty

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
    latitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
    longitude = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Now I have a request handler that when it receives a GET request with a certain flag, and longitude and latitude parameters, it should query the database to find all models that are at a certain distance.

What I did is

```
latitude = float(self.request.get('latitude'))
longitude = float(self.request.get('longitude'))
max_fetch = 20
... 
sin_lat = math.sin(latitude)
cos_lat = math.cos(latitude)
R = 6371 * math.pow(10, 3)
max_distance = 1000
around_you = Model.query(math.acos(sin_lat*math.sin(Model.latitude) + 
                                     cos_lat*math.cos(Model.latitude)*math.cos(longitude - Model.longitude)) * 
                                      R <= max_distance).fetch(max_fetch)
```

But doing this gives me a

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

When I try to do

```
math.sin(Model.latitude)
```

Any hint on how to fix this?

Comment: What if you did `math.sin(latitude)` instead of `math.sin(Model.latitude)`?

Comment: This kind of query isn't possible with the datastore

Answer (score 0):

The datastore, per se, does not support any mathematical operation. You can stash any of those in a `ComputedProperty` (since that's actually computed in your application's Python code just before sending the data to the store with a `.put()`), *but* that doesn't support outside "parameters" -- it must be computed entirely in terms of properties of values on the instance.

So, a `ComputedProperty` could e.g be the `math.sin` of a `FloatProperty` -- but here you appear to require mixing things based on "outside parameters" `latitude` and `longitude`.

Look, rather, into the App Engine Search API, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/ -- *that*, rather than the datastore, appears to offer the functionality you need (specifically via the `GeoPoint` type and `GeoField` field kind).